# Generate 2D coordinate grid in cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to generate a 2D matrix of the following form:

```
(0, 0)  (1, 0)  (2, 0)  (3, 0)
(0, 1)  (1, 1)  (2, 1)  (3, 1)
(0, 2)  (1, 2)  (2, 2)  (3, 2)
(0, 3)  (1, 3)  (2, 3)  (3, 3)
```

In index notation, this matrix may be expressed as `grid[j, i] = (i, j)`.

A simple way to generate this grid would be:

```
auto grid = cv::Mat(height, width, CV_32FC2);

for (auto j = 0; j < height; j++) {
    for (auto i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        grid.at<cv::Vec2f>(j, i) = cv::Point2f(i, j);
    }
}
```

But this may be slow and verbose.

In Python, one can do this:

```
grid = np.dstack(np.meshgrid(np.arange(width), np.arange(height)))
```

What would be a good way to generate a meshgrid of type `cv::Mat` in C++?

Comment: Why you need such grid? Such things usually used in MATLAB or Python to avoid loops. I C++ loops work fast, not need for such grids this case. And if you really need it then the way you show in CPP is ok.

Comment: @AndreySmorodov The reason I need this grid is to apply an affine transform to each point to see where it ends up. Roughly, `transform.dot(grid.reshape(width * height, 2).transpose())` will provide me with a list of locations of where each point ends up under the transform.

Comment: you are missing `{ }` for your inner for loop if i am not misstaken. without the `{ }` only the first following statement will be executed from the nested loop

Comment: Also matrix type should be CV_32FC2.

Comment: @AndreySmorodov in openCV you often want to do the same as in Matlab, that is avoid using loops and accessing values pixel by pixel so that you can use opencv matrix operators instead. It makes your code possible to vectorize as well as more concise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++ loop is likely as fast as the hardware allows. I assume the implicit `static_cast<float>(j)` is moved outside the inner loop by the optimizer.

C++ does have `std::iota` but it only works on a 1D container.

The OpenCV approach would be `cv::Mat::forEach`, which will call your function passing an `int position[2]` for each pixel. The OpenCV docs have a [3D example](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a952ef1a85d70a510240cb645a90efc0d) but it's almost the same as what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

It's going to be faster if you don't use the `at()` method as it is the slowest way of accessing individual values (see the [docs for Mat](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat)). Use `ptr()` instead:

```
for (auto j = 0; j < height; j++) {

    cv::Vec2f* row = grid.ptr<cv::Vec2f>(j);

    for (auto i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        row[i] = cv::Point2f(i, j);
    }
}
```

or pointer to `data` member:

```
cv::Vec2f* arr = (cv::Vec2f*) grid.data;

for (auto j = 0; j < width; j++) {
    for (auto i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        arr[grid.cols*i + j] = cv::Point2f(i, j);
    }
}
```